# How to delete a relationship in this case?

Tags: grails

I have `User` class:

```
class User {
       static hasMany = [ project: Project ]
}
```

and `Project`:

```
class Project {
     static hasMany = [ users : User ]
     static belongsTo = User
}
```

Anywhere in my code I can do this :

```
user.project
```

will return something like :

```
[project name]
```

I need a way to *delete this relationship* for any `User`. How can I do that? I can find a `user` `project` using dynamic finders, criteria query so on, but how do I remove that relationship from a `user` instance?

Very new to Grails.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`removeFrom`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/removeFrom.html).  Example:

```
user.removeFromProject(project)
```

In many-to-many relationships, you should manage the associations from the owning side: the one that is the target of the `belongsTo`.

Note that it would probably be more clear to name the Project association "projects" instead of "project", since it's a many-to-many relationship.